# Spamassassin sa-learn error

Tags: server, postfix, spamassassin

Whenever I try to train `spamassassin` by using:

```
sa-learn -D --showdots --mbox --spam Spam
```

I get the following error:

```
locker: error accessing /home/nerdoflinux/.spamassassin/bayes.lock: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/Locker/UnixNFSSafe.pm line 106.
```

And when I attempt to correct that with(create the file):

```
touch /home/nerdoflinux/.spamassassin/bayes.lock
```

I get:

```
Sep 26 10:49:34.106 [27934] dbg: locker: safe_lock: trying to get lock on /home/nerdoflinux/.spamassassin/bayes with 3 retries
```

and it just counts up the retries (I let it run until over 100 before exiting, and still nothing).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by uncommenting:

```
lock_method flock
```

in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`. Although it states that

```
Set file-locking method (flock is not safe over NFS, but is faster)
```

I think that something is better than nothing. I hope this bug is fixed soon.